# Electron as a WebApplication

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nodejs-server

So I basically made an Electron App. Now I want to port my Electron App to a server. I imagined it like a backend Electron Server, which runs a new instance of the application and "casts the interface through the web". I'm still a student and don't have much experience outside of Electron Client-Side JavaScript. I stumbled over express, and I managed to load the html-File, but I can't load any of my js files.

So basically I want to put my html file on the server, which can use the js files and the node modules loaded with require. Is there a simple and quick way? Because I couldn't find any similar problems on the web

So my application is a Electron Client, which connects to a MSSQL-Database and an AD-Authenitcation-Server. After the user authenticated, the client pulls data from a MSSQL DB and prints it on the html file. I'm using the following modules 
 
"@davistran86/ad": "^1.0.7", 
    "cryptr": "^6.0.2", 
    "electron": "^8.2.3", 
    "jquery": "^3.5.0", 
    "md5": "^2.2.1", 
    "mssql": "^6.2.0", 
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0", 
    "os": "^0.1.1", 
    "ping": "^0.2.3"

And my plan is to port all of those modules and my JS-Files on the Server, which can be used just like an Electron Application by any user who visits the URL

Comment: Could you please post here the structure of your application? Are you still using express or in need of using it?

Comment: @Maf never used express before, tried to describe my application above

Comment: I'm seeing. Is your electron apllication working with the propose you need? Which problems are you facing?

Comment: @Maf my application works fine! I just haven't figured out how to put it on the server so anyone with a simple browser can access it without having to install it on their machine.

And my main problem is loading the app with full node, js and css support onto the server

Comment: In this case my advice is to use express. I only used electron for few purposes (eg., converting my web application to desktop). If you think a good idea to use Express, then I can help (it's quite easy).